# Double colon operator to specify function in do.call

Tags: r, function, call

Suming two vectors using `sum` and its `do.call` equivalent would be

```
sum(1,2)
do.call("sum", list(1,2))
```

Specifying the `sum` function using the double colon operator (`base::sum`) will work in the first but fail in the `do.call` case.

```
base::sum(1,2)
do.call("base::sum", list(1,2))
> Error in `base::sum`(1, 2) : could not find function "base::sum"
```

1. **Is there a way to make `do.call` work with double colons?**
2. **In order to learn: What is happening behind the scenes causing it to
   fail?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the documentation the `what` arg of `do.call` will take `either a function or a non-empty character string naming the function to be called.`

If you try implementing the double colon without the quotes it works:

```
> do.call(base::sum, list(1,2))
[1] 3
```

So while there is a function named `sum` in the package `base`, you can't name the function by also specifying the package. Instead, just remove the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

It *is* possible to use `do.call` to call a double colon operator with package and function that are specified as characters. Since `pkgname::fname` is equivalent to `` `::`(pkgname, fname) `` (i.e., the double colon operator in backticks is a function), where `pkgname` and `fname` can be objects or characters naming objects, we can make `` `::` `` the `what` argument of `do.call` and pass `pkgname` and `fname` (as characters) in a list as the `args` argument. The arguments of the function named by `fname` will then come after the `do.call` call. Thus:

`` do.call(what = `::`, args = list("base", "sum"))(1, 2) ``

Comment: Is there any reason not to implement this as: 
    `do.call(\`::\`("base", "sum"), list(1, 2))`

Comment: Ah, I see that while `do.call(\`::\`("base", "sum"), list(1, 2))` works just fine, `f <- "sum"; do.call(\`::\`("base", f), list(1, 2))` does not, which necessitates `f <- "sum"; do.call(\`::\`, list("base", f))(1, 2)`